# How to restore database

Tags: sql-server

When I try to restore my database I get this screen. The version of the SQL Server is 2012

[image]

Comment: How big is the file? You'll get something that looks like quite like this if the file is in fact empty.

Comment: Run this and ensure the .Bak isn't empty. `RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = <Your Path>`

Comment: you need to select a Database in the dropdown under Destination Section.. or you can Type a Database name.. if it doesn't exist.. it will create a new one with the name you entered in the box

Comment: This is why you would regularly ensure your backups can be restored. It will provide training for the DBA/developer on how to perform a backup, and it gives you an opportunity to verify your backups are as good as you hope they are.

Comment: I have done all that but problem remains intact

Comment: The size of the .bak file is 122 MB

Comment: Version SQL server BACKUP file?

Comment: Version is  2012

Comment: I am getting problem with this file only , I am in doubt is there any security implemented ,If this is the case then any other option to get rid of .

Comment: This could be the Issue with the Log File where Log Size might be greater then the Size of Drive where SQL Is  Install